# Memoization of Intermediate Values In a Typeclass Instance

Tags: haskell, typeclass

I have the following function toTF that, given some context and an item, gives back a function that consumes a piece of input, an input state and produces the next state:

```
class TFSource s' where
    type S s' :: *
    type I s' :: *
    type O s' :: *
    toTF :: Context -> s' -> TFSig (S s') (I s') (O s')

type TFSig s i o = [i] -> s -> Output s i o
```

The instance of this stuff for Token, which I am trying to implement, produces a function that applies the recognizers for the literal value of the token, its stem and part of speech, and, if all is well, accepts this token, otherwise fails.

Here is my attempted instance declaration:

```
instance TFSource Token where
    toTF ctx (Token literal stem) = f
        where (litTF, stemTF) = (toTF ctx literal, toTF ctx stem)
              f (InputToken { .. } : ts) s = ... some computation ...
              f [] _ = Fail
```

How can I make sure that litTF and stemTF are shared (memoized?) across calls to toTF with the same values for ctx and the token?

Comment: If you mean shared across all calls of `toTF`, everywhere, then you can't (except perhaps by changing `TFSig` to `type TFSig s i o = IO (...)`, but I suspect this isn't what you want). If you mean shared across all the same invocations within a single token stream, then you must implement this sharing in the function which consumes the entire token stream, not in the function consuming a single token. But there isn't nearly enough information here about the types involved even to determine how you are consuming the entire token stream, let alone how to implement sharing in that function.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, this will be difficult to do.

One possibility is to refactor your type class so that it provides a single memo trie with no arguments, that lazy contains the results of all possible tokens. You could use something like https://hackage.haskell.org/package/MemoTrie for this purpose. But this assumes that you can actually treat `ctx` as a domain in a map, which may not be possible.